# create new users in db starting at what ID?

Tags: users, mysql, id

I have to create several hundred users using mysql. How do I know which user IDs to give them?  I don't want to duplicate already-in-use IDs, so is there a way to check which IDs are safe to use for new users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t give them IDs. The user ID column in the database is an ‘auto increment’ column, meaning that the value is automatically created whenever a row is added.  So just add your users without an ID and the database will create one for you.

Comment: I thought we were going to test this last Monday but there are delays, haha

anyway, you are saying to just leave the ID col blank for each of the new users?

Comment: Yes, that's right.